# Difficulty with React, Axios, and Spring Boot Applications - Contacting Localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am attempting to use a Google Cloud provided VM to host a React.js front-end that contacts Spring Boot services (that are running in a Docker container). I was able to successfully contact the Spring Boot services, both running locally and remotely, while my React app was on my development machine. Now, however, I am attempting to move the React portion to the cloud as well. However, when I issue a request using the axios.js library:

```
 componentDidMount() {

axios.get(this.props.baseEndpoint + "/inventory")
.then((res) => {
const inv : any = res.data;
console.log(res);
this.setState( {inventory: inv});
});

axios.get(this.props.baseEndpoint + "/category")
.then((res) => {
const cats : any = res.data;
console.log(res);
this.setState( {categories: cats});
});
}
```

where "baseEndpoint" is sourced from a config file:

```
export const BASE_URL : string = "http://localhost";
export const SEARCH_BASE : string = BASE_URL + ":8081/find";
export const INVENTORY_BASE : string = BASE_URL + ":8082";
```

the request fails.

With Firefox Developer's tools, a "Network Error" is logged to the console. However, whenever I switch over to the "Network" tab itself, it is as if the "Get" request is still pending or something. There is no response status (such as 500, 404, 200, etc), and both the "transferred" and "size" fields say 0. The response payload is empty.

The React app is served using a very simplistic Nginx configuration.

```
server { listen 80; 
root /home/kelly/workspace/front-end/distr;
index index.html
location / {}
}
```

However, I can use curl to successfully `GET` the same endpoint (http://localhost:8082/category, for example) just fine. What might the issue be? I have also tried 127.0.0.0.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Request headers from Firefox Developer tools:

```
Accept  
application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding 
gzip, deflate
Accept-Language 
en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  
keep-alive
Host    
localhost:8082
Origin  
http://mysite
Referer 
http://mysite/index.html
User-Agent  
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

Sample output from curl:

```
[{"id":1,"skuCode":"PS1","displayName":"PlayStation"},{"id":2,"skuCode":"PS2","displayName":"PlayStation 2"},{"id":3,"skuCode":"WII","displayName":"WII"},{"id":4,"skuCode":"GBC","displayName":"Gameboy Color"},{"id":5,"skuCode":"GBA","displayName":"Gameboy Advance"},{"id":6,"skuCode":"NDS","displayName":"Nintendo DS"},{"id":7,"skuCode":"N64","displayName":"Nintendo 64"},{"id":8,"skuCode":"GC","displayName":"Gamecube"},{"id":9,"skuCode":"SEG","displayName":"Sega Genesis"}]
```

EDIT TWO:

Networking is not my area of expertise, however, I tried running tcptrack -i eth0 while contacting my application. I see two requests to port 80 (presumably one for my HTML page and one for my .js file) from my local machine/browser. I also see multiple connections from my VM's IP to 169.254.169.254 (which based on this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/427018/what-is-this-ip-address-169-254-169-254), is simply a link-local address associated with cloud providers) and my SSH connection. However, I do not see any requests to port 8081, 8082, or anywhere else for that matter. Not sure if that might help provide some insight.

Thanks again.

Comment: The network tab should tell you more.  Have you opened the network tab and then refreshed?  Perhaps share some of the headers for the request?  What does the curl request give you as a response?

Comment: @bozdoz The details have been added. Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm that the component is mounting?  Just thinking maybe the axios function isn't being called.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In case it helps anyone, I resolved this issue through a change to the nginx configuration file and context (in the xxx.properties file) of the Spring apps.  I had to set up separate `location` blocks within my nginx configuration file. For example:   `location /admin { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082; proxy_redirect off; }`.